# Print unicode character in java

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, unicode-string

Displaying `unicode` character in java shows "?" sign. For example, i tried to print "अ". Its `unicode` Number is U+0905 and html representation is "&#2309;". 
The below codes prints "?" instead of `unicode` character.

```
char aa = '\u0905';
String myString = aa + " result" ;
System.out.println(myString); // displays "? result"
```

Is there a way to display `unicode` character directly from `unicode` itself without using `unicode` numbers? i.e "अ" is saved in file now display the file in jsp.

Comment: May be your **console** isn't able or configured to show that character?

Comment: @sazzad I have tried this in servlet get method. Here also it shows "?" in browser.

Comment: is your request returning utf8?

Comment: If you save your .java or .jsp file in utf-8 then you can use unicode characters in it without encoding

Comment: You are storing your Unicode in a var of type "char."  Put it inside double quotes.

Answer (score 5):

Java defines two types of streams, byte and character.

The main reason why System.out.println() can't show Unicode characters is that System.out.println() is a byte stream that deal with only the low-order eight bits of character which is 16-bits.

In order to deal with Unicode characters(16-bit Unicode character), you have to use character based stream i.e. PrintWriter.

PrintWriter supports the print( ) and println( ) methods. Thus, you can use these methods
in the same way as you used them with System.out.

```
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(System.out,true);
char aa = '\u0905';
printWriter.println("aa = " + aa);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `myString` variable contains the perfectly correct value. The problem must be the output from `System.out.println(myString)` which has to send some bytes to some output to show the glyphs that you want to see.

`System.out` is a PrintStream using the "platform default encoding" to convert characters to byte sequences - maybe your platform doesn't support that character. E.g. on my Windows 7 computer in Germany, the default encoding is CP1252, and there's no byte sequence in this encoding that corresponds to your character.

Or maybe the encoding is correct, but simply the font that creates graphical glyphs from characters doesn't have that charater.

If you are sending your output to a Windows CMD.EXE window, then maybe both reasons apply.

But be assured, your string is correct, and if you send it to a destination that can handle it (e.g. a Swing JTextField), it'll show up correctly.

Answer (score 2):

try to use utf8 character set -

```
        Charset utf8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
        Charset def = Charset.defaultCharset();

        String charToPrint = "u0905";

        byte[] bytes = charToPrint.getBytes("UTF-8");
        String message = new String(bytes , def.name());

        PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(System.out, true, utf8.name());
        printStream.println(message); // should print your character
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem wiht Eclipse. I solved my problem by switching the Encoding format for the console from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8. You can do in the Run/Run Configurations/Common menu.

https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/02/21/pro-tip-unicode-characters-in-the-eclipse-console/

Answer (score 1):

Unicode is a unique code which is used to print any character or symbol.

You can use unicode from --> https://unicode-table.com/en/

Below is an example for printing a symbol in Java.

```
        package Basics;
        
        /**
         *
         * @author shelc
         */
        public class StringUnicode {
        
            public static void main(String[] args) {
        
                String var1 = "Cyntia";
                String var2 = new String(" is my daughter!");
        
                System.out.println(var1 + " \u263A" + var2);
    
                //printing heart using unicode
                System.out.println("Hello World \u2665");
        
            }
        
        }
        
    ******************************************************************
    OUTPUT-->
    
    Cyntia ☺ is my daughter!
    Hello World ♥
```